# create a Flutter background service that works when app killed

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am developing a Flutter app for open source project. Now, I need to run a sort of "always on" background service (not Foreground Service) in order to send notification to user to get updates.

I've already checked those two libraries from pub.dev ([this](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) and [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service), [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background));

these all are working fine but It's showing that "app is running" in notification bar and user can also remove the app from background by click on Exit in recent;

So I need a perfect solution that every app use for these task like I have to update the notification on every events. so please help me!